# Settings the ImageUrl in an ImageButton on a master page with an AppSettings key

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, imagebutton

I'm trying to display the ImageUrl of an asp:ImageButton using AppSettings in my master page like this:

```
 View.Master:
 ....
 <asp:ImageButton ID="aspShowHideButton" ImageUrl='<%# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HomeDirectory").ToString()%>images/arrowUpButton.gif' runat="server" />
```

Unfortunately when I pull this up in the browser, this is the code that's being rendered:

```
 <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$aspContentMain$aspShowHideButton" id="aspContentMain_aspShowHideButton" onmouseover="ShowHideButtonMouseOver()" onmouseout="ShowHideButtonMouseOut()" src="../%3C%25#%20System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(%22HomeDirectory%22).ToString()%25%3Eimages/arrowUpButton.gif" />
```

So it's taking my ImageUrl literally, but I want it to take the value of the key, which is:

```
  ...
  <appSettings>
        ....
        <add key="HomeDirectory" value="/" />
        ....
```

I've tried, removing the "ToString()" function, I've tried "#" and "$" infront of the System.Configuration.... statement.  I've also tinkered with trying to get this to work in the Page_Load function, using:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(....)
    If Not IsNothing(Master.FindControl("aspShowHideButton")) Then
       Dim ShowHideButton As ImageButton = Master.FindControl("aspShowHideButton")
       ShowHideButton.ImageUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HomeDirectory") + "images/arrowUpButton.gif"
    End If
```

But that didn't seem to work either, I'm assuming because it could not find the control I was looking for (ie. aspShowHideButton).

Fundimentally, i want to have a key/value pair in my web.config file that allows me to change where my images are, and I want to be able to use this key/value pair in an ImageButton:ImageUrl on my master page, which seems like it must be a pretty popular thing to do.  Any advise, direction, is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using appsettings in a server tag, use this syntax:

```
<%$ AppSettings:HomeDirectory %>
```

But you won't be able to concatenate the sufix of ImageUrl. Notice that if you want to refer home directory in an asp.net server control, ~ will do the trick.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="aspShowHideButton" ImageUrl="~/images/arrowUpButton.gif" runat="server"/>
```

**The easy solution**

Initialize the ImageUrl property on server side code, say for example the Page_Load event. There you will be able to use whatever server code you want.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       this.aspShowHideButton.ImageUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HomeDirectory").ToString() + "images/arrowUpButton.gif";
    }
}
```

Now, **if you really need** to define that sort of concatenation in the ImageButton tag directly, you will need to use the Code Expression Builder. [Read about that here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx).

With Code Expression Builder, you will be able to use this kind of syntax in your ImageButton tag:

```
ImageUrl="<%$ Code: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HomeDirectory").ToString() + "images/arrowUpButton.gif" %>"
```

Comment: @daniloquio-Updated with another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="<%$ AppSettings:FullPath %>images/image001.jpg" ></asp:ImageButton>
```

(Or) there is a small work aroud for this to work:

Web.Config:

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="testKey" value="images/up.gif" />
</appSettings>
```

Add an image button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" />
```

And from codebehind you can call this way:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ImageButton1.ImageUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testKey"];
    }
```

Comment: Your edit wont work because OP want to have the HomeDirectory in appsettings, not the full path. Obviusly OP could set ImageUrl on Page_Load concatenating appsettings["homeDir"] with the sufix.